# How to read and write psql variables in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need to read psql variables in plpgsql. Seems there is no way to do this, at least I haven't seen solutions.

1) Store some var in psql
2) Read this var in plpgsql and store another var in plpgsql as psql 
variable
3) Read the final psql varible in SQL query

Tried var := :var (not working)
Tried \gset within plpgsql (not working)
Have no idea how to continue

```
            \set var1 100

            SELECT :var1 AS var1;
            >>
            var1
            ------
             100
            (1 row)
            --All good

             --Assign psql variable using \gset
            SELECT 200 AS var2 \gset

            SELECT :var2 AS var2;
            >>
            var2
            ------
             200
            --All good


            DO $$
            DECLARE
            var3 int;
            BEGIN
                --I want to get psql variable var2. This doesn't work
                var3 := :var2;
                --I want to store var3 to psql variable using \gset method. This doesn't work either
                EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || var3 || ' AS var3 \\gset';
            END $$;

            >>
            ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
            LINE 6: var3 := :var2;
                            ^

            --This is what I want in the end
            SELECT :var3 AS var3;
            >>
            ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
            LINE 1: SELECT :var3 AS var3;
                           ^
            --This obviously doesn't work
```

I want to read psql variables in plpgsql, then do something with them and store back as new psql variables to be able to read later in sql query (OUTSIDE plpgsql!!!).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot to do it. `psql` is client - `plpgsql` is server side programming environment. Both application are running on different environments - theoretically and often on different computers, and every time inside different processes. So you cannot to touch `psql` variable from `plpgsql`. This feature is not supported.

There is a workaround - you can use a server side configuration variables, that are accessible from SQL language and then are accessible from both (client, server) sides.